# Input Range Slider - Jump ONLY from 1 node to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slider input, it slides smoothy from left to right and from right to left.  There are certain nodes from 20 to 100 go along the slider.  Please see my code snippet.

When it slides, I want the slider's thumb sniffs a nearest node and snaps the thumb right on this node. In other words, I want slider jumps to each note only (never stop in between nodes).

Please give me a hand.  Thanks!

```js
const
    range = document.getElementById('range'),
   devicesRange = document.getElementById('devices-range'),
    setValue = ()=>{
        const
            newValue = Number( (range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min) ),
            newPosition = 10 - (newValue * 0.2);
        devicesRange.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}</span>`;
        devicesRange.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
    };
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue);
document.getElementById("range").oninput = function() {
  this.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, ' + this.value + '%, transparent ' + this.value + '%, transparent 100%)'
};
```

```css
.range-wrap{
    /* width: 500px; */
    position: relative;

}
#range {
  width: 100%;
  
transition: background 450ms ease-in;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.devices-range-value{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}
.devices-range-value span{
    width: 30px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);

}
#scales {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
.col5 {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}
.col5 span {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 15px;
    right: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.col5::after {
  content: "";
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-top:-2px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-wrap">
        <input id="range" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1">
        <div class="devices-range-value" id="devices-range"></div>
        <div id="scales">
     
          <div class="col5"><span>10</span></div>
          <div class="col5"><span>100</span></div>
          <div class="col5"><span>500</span></div>
          <div class="col5"><span>1</span></div>
          <div class="col5"><span>10</span></div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the step property in your `<input>` tag to 20, value to 0 and min to 0. That will force your input range to jump right to the points you want.

```js
const
    range = document.getElementById('range'),
   devicesRange = document.getElementById('devices-range'),
    setValue = ()=>{
        const
            newValue = Number( (range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min) ),
            newPosition = 10 - (newValue * 0.2);
        devicesRange.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}</span>`;
        devicesRange.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
    };
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue);
document.getElementById("range").oninput = function() {
  this.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, ' + this.value + '%, transparent ' + this.value + '%, transparent 100%)'
};
```

```css
.range-wrap{
    /* width: 500px; */
    position: relative;

}
#range {
  width: 100%;
  
transition: background 450ms ease-in;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.devices-range-value{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}
.devices-range-value span{
    width: 30px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);

}
#scales {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
.col5 {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}
.col5 span {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 15px;
    right: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.col5::after {
  content: "";
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-top:-2px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-wrap">
        <input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="20">
        <div class="devices-range-value" id="devices-range"></div>
        <div id="scales">
          <div class="col5"><span>20</span></div>
          <div class="col5"><span>40</span></div>
          <div class="col5"><span>60</span></div>
          <div class="col5"><span>80</span></div>
          <div class="col5"><span>100</span></div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank Daniel Karam for showing me a way to get it work!  It works as expected.  I have a small question: I set and show 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 by using `<div class="col5"><span>...</span></div>`, I wonder if in `input` can I show these numbers without using codes like I do?

Comment: There is a property called 'label' that you can use in a `<option>` tag wrapped by a `<datalist>` tag (also you should set an 'id' property to your `<datalist>` tag for later use). Then you set a property 'list' in your `<input>` tag with the `<datalist>` tag id. But, unfortunately, this feature is not supported yet in major browsers as you can check in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range). For now, it's better to use alternatives tag (like you did) for labeling.

Comment: Thank Daniel Karam for explanation! I will keep the way I have for now. There is an issue:  the range doesn't set like 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 anymore, it sets 10, 100, 500, 1, 10.  So, we set a step= 20, that is a right value for each point range, but every time it  jumps right to the points, the values are different.  For example, when it jumps to a point of 100, the value shows 20.  I try to fix this issue, but not success.  Any ideas, please give a hand.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you change only the HTML file or did you change another file? If you didn't, you can copy my HTML snippet in this answer and check if it's working. If not, check my code at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/danielkv7/pen/GRoZNQp) and compare with your code to see the differences.

Comment: Yes, I changed HTML file from1, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 to 1, 10, 100, 500, 1, 10.  There are still 5 ranges, but the values should be different.  By default it is at first point and shows 1, then it jumps to second point, it will show 10.  When it jumps to the third point, it will show 100, then fourth point will show 500 and so on.

Comment: Now I understood your doubt. I tried to find some resource to check if it's possible to use `input` range with non continuous values, but I didn't find any resource. What you could try to do is to create a new `input` with type property set to "hidden" to store the value you want to set. But for this, you have to create a script in your js.file to transform your value in your `input` range before storing to the hidden `input`. For instance, your slide your `input` range to 100, then your script transform this value to 40 and stores in your hidden `input`.

Comment: Actually, you could reuse your `div` with id "devices-range" instead of `input` hidden.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215770/discussion-between-abcid-d-and-daniel-karam).

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I did answer at the chat later. But you can check I what I meant at this link: https://codepen.io/danielkv7/pen/wvMGqBQ